# How to Concatenate a specific Value in column when Conditions are matching?

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have a SQL Code which i am trying to Convert into Pyspark?
The SQL Query looks like this: I need to Concatenate '0' at starting of 'ADDRESS_HOME' if the below Query Conditions Satisfies.

```
   UPDATE STUDENT_DATA 
   SET STUDENT_DATA.ADDRESS_HOME = "0" & [STUDENT_DATA].ADDRESS_HOME
   WHERE (((STUDENT_DATA.STATE_ABB)="TURIN" Or
   (STUDENT_DATA.STATE_ABB)="RUSH" Or 
   (STUDENT_DATA.STATE_ABB)="MEXIC" Or 
   (STUDENT_DATA.STATE_ABB)="VINTA") 
   AND ((Len([ADDRESS_HOME])) < "5"));
```

Thank you in Advance for your responses

```
# +---+---------------+---------+
# | ID|ADDRESS_HOME   | STATE_ABB|
# +---+---------------+---------+
# |  1|      7645     |RUSH      |
# |  2|      98364    |MEXIC     |
# |  3|      2980     |TURIN     |
# |  4|      6728     |VINTA     |
# |  5|       128     |VINTA     |


EXPECTED OUTPUT
# +---+---------------+---------+
    # | ID|ADDRESS_HOME   | STATE_ABB|
    # +---+---------------+---------+
    # |  1|      07645     |RUSH      |
    # |  2|      98364     |MEXIC     |
    # |  3|      02980     |TURIN     |
    # |  4|      06728     |VINTA     |
    # |  5|      0128      |VINTA     |
```

Comment: What's the data type of column "ADDRESS_HOME"? String or int?

Comment: ADDRESS_HOME is of String_Type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to align the ADDRESS_HOME to be 5 digits and pad with 0, you can use `lpad`.

```py
df = df.withColumn('ADDRESS_HOME', F.lpad('ADDRESS_HOME', 5, '0'))
```

If you want only pad with 1 char (`0`), when the ADDRESS_HOME has less than 5 chars.

```py
df = (df.withColumn('ADDRESS_HOME', F.when(F.length('ADDRESS_HOME') < 5, F.concat(F.lit('0'), F.col('ADDRESS_HOME'))))
                                     .otherwise(F.col('ADDRESS_HOME')))
```

UPDATE:

You can convert all OR criteria to IN clause(`isin`) then use logical AND with the other criteria.

```py
states = ['RUSH', 'MEXIC', 'TURIN', 'VINTA']

df = (df.withColumn('ADDRESS_HOME', 
                    F.when(F.col('STATE_ABB').isin(states) & (F.length('ADDRESS_HOME') < 5), 
                           F.concat(F.lit('0'), F.col('ADDRESS_HOME')))
                     .otherwise(F.col('ADDRESS_HOME'))))
```

Comment: hi @Emma, i din't want to do padding here

Comment: There are other conditions also which needs to be satisfied but in your Query you have just passed one condition

Answer (score 1):

First you filter, your DF serching for the values you want to update.

Then you update the columns (First withcolumn)

After updating, you join your updated DF with your original dataframe (do this to get all values in one dataframe again). And do a coalesce to the FINAL ADDRESS

Finally, you select the values from the original DF (Id and State) and the updated value (Final_Address...since you did a coalesce, the values not updated will not be null, they are going to be the update value on the filtered condition, and the original value on the condition not matched in the filter).

**This answer should solve your problem, BUT, @Emma answers is more efficient.**

```
df = df.filter(
            (f.col("STATE_ABB").isin(f.lit("TURIN"), f.lit("RUSH"), f.lit("TURIN"), f.lit("VINTA")) &
            (f.len("ADDRESS_HOME") < 5)
        ).withColumn(
            "ADDRESS_HOME_CONCAT",
            f.concat(f.lit("0"),f.col("ADDRESS_HOME"))
        ).alias("df_filtered").join(
            df.alias("original_df"),
            on=f.col("original_df.Id") == f.col("df_filtered.Id")
            how='left'
        ).withColumn(
          "FINAL_ADDRESS",
          f.coalesce(f.col("df_filtered.ADDRESS_HOME_CONCAT"), f.col("original_df.ADDRESS_HOME")
    ).select(
            f.col("original_df.Id").alias("Id"),
            f.col("FINAL_ADDRESS").alias("ADDRESS_HOME"),
            f.col("original_df.STATE_ABB").alias("STATE_ABB")
        )
```

Sorry for any typo missing, I've posted it from my cellphone!

Comment: hi @OdiumPura, can you please explain a little bit about your Query

Comment: I've update the answer with an explanation.